# SQL Group by on outer reference after 2 inner joins

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2012

My sql query is not working as intended, in its current form it will return results, but some of them on the **second** column are duplicated, or in other words, some the computer names followed by the drive letter show twice.

The query is this:

```
(select Distinct 'ServerDrive' as storageType, cast(assetname as 
varchar)+ '\ ' +cast(caption as varchar) as storagePath,((rqDiskdrivesHist. 
[size]-rqDiskdrivesHist.[freespace])/1024/1024) as usedMB,(rqDiskdrivesHist. 
[size]/1024/1024) as sizeMB from lansweeperdb.dbo.tblAssets 
inner join rqDiskdrivesHist
on lansweeperdb.dbo.tblAssets.AssetID=rqDiskdrivesHist.AssetID 
where drivetype=3
and lansweeperdb.dbo.tblAssets.AssetName in
(select distinct entitypath from rqcentities
inner join rqcustomer
on rqcentities.customerID=rqcustomer.customerID 
where customername like '%ak 26%' and entityType='computer'
and not (
(AssetName like 'WFP3675' and caption like 'D:')
or
(AssetName like 'WFP3675' and caption like 'E:')
or
(AssetName like 'WFP3675' and caption like 'F:')
or
(AssetName like '%00500%')
)  
))
```

If I try to group by at the end. with:

```
GROUP BY cast(assetname as varchar)+'\'+cast(caption as varchar)
```

I will get the "Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.
" error.

Edit: These are 2 rows from the results which are duplicated.

[image]

Comment: The space after the slash was added just for the sake of code coloring. `cast(assetname as 
varchar)+ '\ ' +cast(caption as varchar)` should be treated as `cast(assetname as 
varchar)+ '\' +cast(caption as varchar)`.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it and your desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group on the alias instead as you did not expose those fields in the inner query.

```
SELECT
    storageType,
    storagePath,
    MaxMB = MAX(usedMB),
    MinMB = MIN(usedMB),
    AvgMB = AVG(usedMB)
FROM
(
    select 'ServerDrive' as storageType, 
    cast(assetname as varchar)+ '\ ' +cast(caption as varchar) as storagePath,
    ((rqDiskdrivesHist.[size]-rqDiskdrivesHist.[freespace])/1024/1024) as usedMB,
    (rqDiskdrivesHist.[size]/1024/1024) as sizeMB 
    from 
        lansweeperdb.dbo.tblAssets 
        inner join rqDiskdrivesHist on lansweeperdb.dbo.tblAssets.AssetID=rqDiskdrivesHist.AssetID 
    where 
        drivetype=3
        and lansweeperdb.dbo.tblAssets.AssetName in
        (
            select distinct entitypath 
            from rqcentities
            inner join rqcustomer on rqcentities.customerID=rqcustomer.customerID 
            where customername like '%ak 26%' and entityType='computer'
            and not (
                        (AssetName like 'WFP3675' and caption like 'D:')
                        or
                        (AssetName like 'WFP3675' and caption like 'E:')
                        or
                        (AssetName like 'WFP3675' and caption like 'F:')
                        or
                        (AssetName like '%00500%')
                    )  
        )
) AS X
GROUP BY
    storagePath,
    storageType
```

Comment: Could you show how the whole query would look like?

Comment: @lason - Added a way to return one record for each path and type.

Comment: @lason - Note I removed the distinct as it is a group field. Also, you don't really need the StorageType in the inner join as you are limiting it to one hard coded value.